# How to send multiple variable using xmlhttp.open?

Tags: ajax, get

Ok i have this piece of code from which i took from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_database):-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showCustomer(str)
{
var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action=""> 
<select name="customers" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a customer:</option>
<option value="ALFKI">Alfreds Futterkiste</option>
<option value="NORTS ">North/South</option>
<option value="WOLZA">Wolski Zajazd</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint">Customer info will be listed here...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now i made a form and i am passing two variables, so how i will pass the value of two variables in this `xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?q="+str,true);`. As this thing has not been included.

Comment: Why don't you engage JQuery, it simple as it can be...

Comment: jQuery can also do that? do you have any source link that i can refer and can get a start to learn.

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886878/can-i-get-more-variables-instead-of-string-in-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy. for the first variable, you use ?, for variables after that, you use &. For example.

```
var variables = "name=David&string=Hello World";
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?" + variables,true);
```

And to get variables form other forms, set them to have ID's (easiest way), and do

```
document.getElementById('theid').value;
```

Comment: if i want to send two values from `onchange="showCustomer(this.value)`, and similarly let the function know that it needs to get two variables.

Comment: I am unable to understand this piece of code `document.getElementById('theid').value;` could you help me to understand. Please

Comment: @David I tried it but didn't work with me? always choose the last variable?