# How to send multiple variables with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: ajax

I try to send two variables with Ajax request to my `ajax.php`:

```
var xhReq               = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhReq.open              ( "GET", "ajax.php", false );
xhReq.setRequestHeader  ("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhReq.send              ("cmd=ping&url=www.google.com");
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send multiple variable using xmlhttp.open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956884/how-to-send-multiple-variable-using-xmlhttp-open)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing some values.

A GET request:

```
xhReq.open( "GET", "ajax.php?cmd=ping&url=www.google.com", true );
xhReq.send();
```

A POST request:

```
xhReq.open( "POST", "ajax.php", true );
xhReq.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
xhReq.send( "cmd=ping&url=www.google.com" );
```

Answer (score 1):

`//main page: javascript function

function ajaxSave(whatToSave,fileToSaveIn){

... etc.

xmlhttp.open("POST","secondaryPage.php",true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.send("whatToSave=" + whatToSave + "&" + "fileToSaveIn=" + fileToSaveIn + "");
}

//secondary page: PHP code

$myFile = $_POST["fileToSaveIn"];

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

$stringData = $_POST["whatToSave"];

fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hellow clarke, welcome to stackoverflow. Please format your answer correctly.